# Sort by comments and placing liked ones on top

Tags: mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I've got a Comments database schema that goes like this:

```
Comments: {
    postId: '',
    body: '',
    upvotedBy: [],
    upvotes: 0
}
```

The upvotedBy holds the UserIds of users who upvote it. Upvotes holds the number of total upvotes the comment has received. My Comments.find() is as follows:

```
return Comments.find({ 
    'postId': this._id 
}, { 
    sort: { 
        'submitted': -1
    }
});
```

So I'm looking for something to add to the sort bit, to look for the current logged in user's Id in the upvotedBy array, and if it is, have the list sorted in a way that the upvoted comment by the current user is listed first. Is this possible? Looking for vaguely something like:

```
..
    sort: { 
        'submitted': -1,
        'upvotedBy' as upvotedByUser: checkIfInArray(userId)
    }
..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is just to fetch two sets of documents: those that contain the current user's comments, and those that don't. If each set is sorted by `submitted`, then you need only concat the results. For example:

```js
var userId = Meteor.userId();
var sort = {sort: {submitted: -1}};

var myComments = Comments.find({
  postId: this._id,
  upvotedBy: userId
}, sort).fetch();

var otherComments = Comments.find({
  postId: this._id,
  upvotedBy: {$ne: userId}
}, sort).fetch();

myComments.concat(otherComments);
```

Comment: Oh, so mongo automatically searches within arrays huh? Right now, if I don't add in the fetch() after the find(), the last line is throwing an error "Exception in template helper: TypeError: undefined is not a function". If I add fetch() in, I don't see any results :/

Comment: You need the `fetch` in both cases because you need 2 arrays (not cursors). Make sure to `return myComments.concat(otherComments);`. If that doesn't work, try doing a `console.log` of each intermediate result.

Comment: Ah dope. Yeah, it was the return. Works now, though had to do it the other way around: return otherComments.concat(myComments) to have the liked ones on top. Another workaround I had earlier was having the two calls as separate template helpers, and I had {{#if postsWithLikes}} and {{# posts}} in the template. Thanks for the help.